# Can't get the page using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup, httpurlconnection

There is a problem when it tries to page in a normal java class everything works fine, but if this is done already in the android app, the answer comes "you don't have permission to access" while the user-agent is specified in the android manifest has the permission to use the Internet and all this in a separate thread, can someone faced with this problem

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            go();
        }
    }).start();
}
 private void go()
{

    try {
        document = Jsoup.connect("http://issa.beltelecom.by/main.html").userAgent("Chrome 53.0.2785.143").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running it in a background task?

Comment: Yes of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be important to set the `Accept` header field (*note: tested on Android 5.1.1 device*).

In general: if the connection is refused using jsoup, inspect the requests (for example using the networks tab in the chrome dev tools/F12) and add missing header fields.

**Example Code**

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36";
String url = "https://issa.beltelecom.by/main.html";
String acceptValue = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
String host = "issa.beltelecom.by";

document = Jsoup.connect(url).header("Accept",acceptValue).header("Host", host).userAgent(userAgent).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, set your OnClickListener to call the background task.

```
new MyAsyncTask().execute();
```

Then perform your task

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                //do anything here
            }

            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...param) {

                Document document = null;
                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect(getString(R.string.your_url_string)).get();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (document != null) {
                    Elements yourElements = document.select("#element_id");

                    //Do anything here
                    return true;
                }
                //Document is null
                return false;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if(result==true) {
                    // do this
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: this does not work, here the main problem is that server blocks access to the page although, if I run the same code in a normal java class everything is working

Comment: If you run the code in a normal Java class and it runs, then i guess it's not your server that blocks it. But you are doing something wrong.